# Limit of translates of characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This might be silly, but what is a simple way of showing that given a characteristic function of a lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ then we have 
$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \chi (x-t) \rightarrow \chi(x)$ almost everywhere? This looks obvious, but is there an easy way to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\{\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \chi_A (x-t) \nrightarrow \chi_A(x)\}$ is exactly the boundary of $A$, so the convergence holds a.e. iff the boundary has zero measure. Which is not always the case - [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).